# Count function in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a set of data looks like this:

```
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
1     <--
1
1
1
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
1     <--
1
1
1
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
```

My question is how do I count the total of the first `1` in the column?

Comment: Heya, I hate to say this but your question is terribly formatted. I'm not even sure if the proposed edit is correct. Could you check and approve it if it is, and/or use codeblocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best way to deal with this question, but it worked perfectly fine in my test.

Assuming you only have the values `FALSE` and `1` in this particular column and that this column is `A`, and the first value is at `A2`. Put the following formula in `B2` (or any cell you like, but you will need to modify the formula).

`=IF(A2<>A1, IF(A2=1, "1", "not 1"), "not 1")`

This will compare the value to the left of the formula with the value above it, if they match it gets ignored. If they don't match then it must be either the first `FALSE` or `1` value in the block.

The nested `IF` statement then determines if this value is a `FALSE` or `1`. If it is `FALSE` it gets ignored and marked as `not 1` and if it *is* a `1`, then it's marked as `1`. We'll use this value later.

You will then need to copy this down the entire length of your spreadsheet (remember when I said this may not be the best?).

Once you have your test column values all figured out, a simple `COUNTIF` can be used to count the number of matched cells that contain `1`.

Usage:

`=COUNTIF(RANGE, CONDITION)`

Example:

If your data is in column `A`:

`=COUNTIF(A1:A41, 1)`

Hope this does what you need!

---

**EDIT:** If you want a nice tidy looking reference column you can use the following to only pick out the first `1` of each block:

`=IF(A2<>A1, IF(A2=1, "1", ""), "")`

Comment: Thanks  Michael for your reply.  I need to count the first "1" that occurs in a role of "1"s  that separated by multiple "False". so there maybe 118 first "1"s but total of "1" might be 10000. i don't know if that make sense.

Comment: Oh right! My mistake, give me a bit and I'll work this out.

Comment: @SophiaLiu Hi Sophia, I've updated my answer with a method that should work for you.

Comment: Hi, Michael Thanks a lot. The formula works great.

Comment: @SophiaLiu If this answer works for you, please mark it as accepted by checking the green tick.

Answer (score 1):

For Excel >= 2007 only:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A1048575, "=FALSE", A2:A1048576, "=1")+N(A1=1)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work correctly in Excel 2010 (at least). It gives me a total one less than the actual number of blocks.

Comment: Maybe you started the test column with a 1's block? Excel 2010 here too, it does work as expected.

Comment: What if the users spreadsheet starts with a block of 1's?

Comment: Your solution wouldn't work either... I followed the given example.

Comment: My method works perfectly fine: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UuvcS.jpg

Comment: You added a top raw... whatever. (You could have adjusted my formula accordingly then). Fixed mine to be general. Cheers

Comment: What does NUM do? I can't find that in Excel 2010.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26413/discussion-between-salvof-and-michael-frank).